# Why does a Promise return as <Pending> after .then?

Tags: node.js

So I have this code;

```
function getUserData(serverID, userID) {
    connectToDB().then(() => {
        console.log(2);
        let result = doesUserExist(serverID, userID).then(() => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
}
```

&

```
function doesUserExist(serverID, userID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve(PlayerModel.exists({serverID: serverID, userID: userID}));
    });
}
```

I want the console.log(result) to return the result of doesUserExist() after it's finished processing, but I'm getting the result Promise {  } printed, instead.

I thought .this() only executes after the promise is fulfilled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `result` is not the `Promise` returned by `doUserExist` but from `.then` chain, which won't be resolved after that `.then` finishes, which can never happen inside that `.then`

```
let result = prom(serverID, userID);

result.then(() => {
   console.log(result); // Resolved
});
```

---

`.then` returns a **new** `Promise`.

```js
let promiseA = doesUserExist(serverID, userID);
let promiseB = promiseA
   .then(() => console.log(promiseA, promiseB)) // Resolved, Pending
```

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Is there any standard as to how they should be chained together? I can imagine with larger promises it'll get quite messy.

Comment: You can chain as many as you want, nowadays you should probably use `async/await` which is cleaner.